# Обособление оборота с союзом «словно»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сравнительный-оборот, сравнение

Меня заинтересовало такое предложение:

*Но все и так были, **словно хмельные*** (Б. Акунин).

Оборот вроде бы входит в состав сказуемого. Можно ли здесь поставить запятую, как это сделал автор, и как ее в этом случае объяснить?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Честно — объяснить такую пунктуацию сложно (иначе и вопроса бы не возникло). Не знаю, сколько раз я произнес это предложение, — много. Сказать, что это авторский знак, противоречащий правилам, нельзя. Предложение вроде бы читается без паузы с неизменным, бóльшим или меньшим, ударением на ***тАк*** и на ***хмельнЫе***. Хотя "микроскопический люфт" после ***были*** всё же есть в результате первого повышения тона, но это не дает основания для запятой. Если же автор все-таки задумывал паузу, то на его месте я бы поставил многоточие: ***Но все и так были... словно хмельные.***

Может, это ошибка корректоров в определенных изданиях? По крайней мере, поисковик мне выдал [**это предложение без запятой**](https://books.google.ru/books?id=rF-SDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT4406&lpg=PT4406&dq=%D0%9D%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%20%D0%B8%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B8,%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D1%85%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20(%D0%91.%20%D0%90%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD)&source=bl&ots=LA0Oi8jmjq&sig=ACfU3U2vp371PpSJ8BmvQQjfBTmmJzCXJg&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjy4bSJjMHqAhUU6aYKHW9rBfgQ6AEwAHoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%9D%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%20%D0%B8%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B8%2C%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D1%85%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20(%D0%91.%20%D0%90%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD)&f=false).

Вы наверняка обращались к Нацкорпусу. По запросу ***был/была/было/были словно*** он выдает 417 документов. Исключая те, в которых запятая ставится по другим причинам (их не так много), можно найти только **шесть** случаев, подходящих под наш и, так же как рассматриваемое предложение, имеющих запятую. Позволю себе привести их все:

*Способные, вдумчивые, одушевленные, непосредственные ― они **были, словно свежие полевые цветки**, всем существом своим жадно тянущиеся к солнцу...* [В. М. Чернов. Записки социалиста революционера (1922)]

*И тишина **была, словно отлитая из меди**, ударить по ней ― и зазвучит.* [В. А. Никифоров-Волгин. Дорожный посох (1923-1938)]

*...у него никого на свете не было, она ему **была, словно дочка***. [митрополит Антоний (Блум). О Божественной литургии (1974)]

*...вот, надо так вжиться в молитву, чтобы уже не надо было ползти от слова к слову, чтобы эти слова **были, словно рука Божия**, коснувшаяся меня…* [митрополит Антоний (Блум). Ответы на вопросы о молитве (1975-1985)]

*Мы сидели безнадежно и твердо, и мужчины наши **были, словно в переливающемся панцире**, в лоснящейся грязи...* [Любовь Кабо. Правдёнка (1997)]

*Он **был, словно конь**, остановленный на всём скаку.* [Алексей Иванов. Сердце Пармы (2000)]

И есть один пример с **тире**:

*Оно **было ― словно тот «вырубленный лес»**, про который говорит поэт.* [В. М. Чернов. Перед бурей. Воспоминания (1953)]

Такой вариант мне нравится и не вызывает никакого отторжения, вероятно потому, что является наглядным примером интонационного тире — сильного знака. Но этот приём, на мой взгляд, не вписывается в предложение Акунина. Особенно если увидеть его в окружении других:

> Шли налегке. Единственной ношей была заплечная сумка с провизией. Гарри строго объявил, что, пока сокровище не будет найдено и вынесено, к спиртному прикладываться запрещено. **Но все и так были словно хмельные**. Проныра приплясывал от возбуждения, Клещ беспрестанно кусал свои тонкие губы.

Comment: Думаю, Ваши рассуждения правильны. Помимо Вашей ссылки, вот здесь без запятой: http://www.virlib.ru/read/17/08262/22.html. И здесь: http://vtabakerke.ru/page,94,boris-akunin-sokol-i-lastochka.html.

Comment: Спасибо, Александр, уже просто своим ответом вы меня очень порадовали. При возможности я внимательное прочитаю его и отвечу вам.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Спасибо за поддержку!

Answer (score 1):

Ответ-комментарий

Александр, вот опять мы с вами не думаем в одном направлении! Впрочем, я не теряю надежду вас «перевоспитать».  Шутка, конечно, но доля правды в ней есть. Чтобы успешно решать такие задачи,  необходимо два условия: умение работать с правилами и способность (а также желание) слышать устную речь.  Оба эти качества у вас есть, а они не часто встречаются. Ведь что ни говорили бы, пунктуация основана на **интонационно-грамматическом принципе**, одной грамматикой здесь не обойдешься.

А теперь о деле.  История такая: я  обратила внимание на предложение, когда читала книгу. В Нацкорус не заглядывала, а  **решение автора одобрила сразу**, но это было **интонационное** решение. Мне же захотелось узнать, можно ли эту запятую объяснить только грамматически. Но вижу, что нельзя.

Интонационный анализ

Итак, приведенное предложение имеет два варианта постановки знаков (с запятой и без нее): (1)   Но все и так были словно хмельные. (2)  Но все и так были, словно хмельные

**Рассмотрим первый вариант.**

Это простое предложение, и интонация у него стандартная: две фразы, разделенные произносительной паузой, два ударения. А вот **расположение** этой паузы, а также **ударений**  не вполне понятно, возможны варианты:
Но все и тАк // были словно хмельнЫе. Но все и так бЫли // словно хмельнЫе.

Недостатки такие: **неопределенность** (два неизвестных параметра) и **невыразительность.** Как решить проблему?

И здесь я предлагаю отвлечься и рассмотреть один **мой любимый пример из Горького**: ***ЖИли Артамоновы // ни с кем не знакомясь.*** Будем считать его отдельным предложением. Обычно его в таком виде приводят в учебниках и спорят о необходимости запятой.

Для чего делается **инверсия?** Автор хочет выделить ударением слово ***жили***, но ведь и при нормальном порядке слов на этот глагол падает ударение: *Артамоновы жИли // ни с кем не знакОмясь.*

Но  это **тоническое ударение** (в конце первой  фразы), оно ничего не выделяет, поэтому  глагол нужно надо **сместить с этой позиции хотя бы на одно слово**, то есть инверсировать.

А вот паузу здесь можно сделать только в одном месте, обозначать ее специально нет смысла (поэтому она произносительная).  Грамматику объясняем так:  деепричастный оборот используется как наречие (жили замкнуто) и не обособляется.

**А теперь вернемся к нашему предложению.** Автор хочет выделить местоимение **ТАК**  логическим ударением, поэтому оно должно быть **удалено от паузы**, но ведь и **паузу нужно обозначить** (она у нас пока еще неопределенная). И мы сразу получаем единственное решение: пауза нужно сделать перед союзом СЛОВНО, вот и приходится там ставить запятую: ***Но все и тАк были  // словно хмельнЫе.***

Как другим это объяснить? Авторское обособление сравнительного оборота, логическое выделение местоимения, подчеркнутая пауза. Но теперь мы знаем, что это н**е прихоть автора, а очень правильный шаг.** Только так мы можем уйти от неопределенной и невыразительной интонации и  помочь читателю в выборе наилучшего варианта прочтения.

И теперь я смотрю **ваши записи**: невыраженная микропауза, не совсем определенное ударение – вот это как раз и не устраивало автора.

**Далее рассмотрим  примеры и дадим оценку каждому.**

*Способные, вдумчивые, одушевленные, непосредственные ― они были, словно свежие полевые цветки, всем существом своим жадно тянущиеся к солнцу.*   Неверно.  Пауза не сочетается с интонацией  всего предложения.

- *И тишинА была, словно отлитая из мЕди, ударить по ней ― и зазвучит.*  Авторская пунктуация.
- ...*у него никого на свете не было, онА ему была, словно дОчка.* Авторская пунктуация.

...*вот, надо так вжиться в молитву, чтобы уже не надо было ползти от слова к слову, чтобы эти слова были, словно рукА Божия, коснувшаяся меня.* Неверно.  Пауза не сочетается с интонацией  всего предложения.

*Мы сидели безнадежно и твердо, и мужчины наши были, словно в переливающемся панцире, в лоснящейся грязи.*  Неверно. Обособленный оборот сложно прочесть, его надо перенести в конец предложения.

*Он был, словно конь, остановленный на всём скаку.* Неверно. Пауза не сочетается с интонацией  всего предложения.

- *ОнО было ― словно тот «вырубленный лЕс», про который говорит поЭт.* Авторская пунктуация.

Итак, одобрить  авторскую пунктуацию можно **только в трех примерах  из семи**.   И это информация для редакторов: не всё, что хочет автор, можно пропускать.

Comment: Sharon, спасибо! Хочется еще пообсуждать, но потом...